# How to store data of the subcategories table with different coloumns for each subcategory table for Products?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm new to database designing. I'll use MySQL and PHP. I'm designing a database in which I have a lot of category and subcategory like given below:

```
Product Table
  p_id
  p_title
  category_id   F Key

Category_Table
  c_id
  c_name

Sub_category_Table
  sc_id
  sc_name
  c_id      F Key
```

Now, the problem is, for example, I have 8 Categories and almost over 60 subcategories with some common coloumn names and some quite different like this:

```
Vehicle                           // a category
  Car                          // subcategory
      id,
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year
      insurance_validity_date
      fuel_type

  Motorcycle                          // subcategory
      id
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year

  Bus/Lorry                          // subcategory
      id
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year
      insurance_validity_date
      fuel_type
```

Now I'm merging all the same columns in one table named 'Vehicle' and making a new table named 'car' to store 'insurance_validity_date, fuel_type' columns and  no table for Motorcycles at all like this:

```
Vehicle (= Motorcycle)                           // a category
      id
      cat_id
      brand_id
      model
      price
      year

 Car/Bus                          // subcategory
      id
      insurance_validity_date
      fuel_type
      vehicle_id
```

It means no need to create Motorcycle table and Car and Bus will be stored in one single table. Is it right?
 1. Motorcycle is a Vehicle
 2. Car is a Vehicle
 3. Bus is a Vehicle

## 'vehicle_id' will identify whether the record is about bus or car

Another example like this is for users. I've three type of users: admin, registered and guest with the following schema:

```
Person
  user
      id
      name
      user_name
      email
      contact_no
      password
      no_of_log_ins
      last_login_time
      registration_date
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

  business_owner
      id
      name
      user_name
      company_business_shop_name
      email
      contact_no
      address
      password
      no_of_log_ins
      last_login_time
      registration_date
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

   guest
      id
      name
      email
      contact_no
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

   admin
      id
      name
      email
      contact_no
      password
      no_of_logins
      last_login_time
      user_role_or_type_id
```

Now I'm merging all the same columns in one table named 'Person' and modifying 'user', 'guest' and 'admin', to store uncommon columns like this:

```
Person (= Guest)
      id
      name
      email
      contact_no
      city
      user_role_or_type_id

   guest
     id
     Person_id

   registered_user (or admin)
      id
      person_id
      user_name
      password
      no_of_logins
      last_login_time

          admin
             id
             registered_user_id

          user
             id                              
             registration_date
             registered_user_id

          business_owner
             id
             company_business_shop_name
             address
             registered_user_id
```

This model means:

1. Guest is a Person
2. Registered user is a Person 
   (i)   user is a Registered User
   (ii)  business_owner is a Registered User

That's all what I think a solution for me. Is it a good solution? Would it not degrade the performance? Should I look for any other solution? Can any of you guide me in this regard??????

Comment: Your question is way too long. As for the top half, I would have just **one table**, vehicle table adding a char or whatever vehicleType. Make several columns nullable (sadly) and hope you don't collect junk

Comment: mysql is a bad choice for hierarchical data

Comment: K thanks Neil, and what about 'user', guest', 'admin' and 'business_owner' table?

Comment: Shortly, I like how you reorganized tables and in my opinion it is a right way to do it. Performance-wise, you will have small degradation of performance when you are searching for all vehicles (compared to single table with null columns suggested by Drew) because of additional join, but is a kind of a cleaner way to do the job. Your proposed design also follows basic relational database design rules and normalization principles.

Comment: Another plus for your design is it provides data consistency, because each of user's details is on single place, so you don't have to modify name, email, etc. on several places (if user belongs to several types at the same time).